# WriteToServerAsync Not working as expected when Upgrade to .net 6

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, sqlbulkcopy, sqlclient

My current project was in .net 5 which I have upgraded to .net 6 version.
Earlier the code was working fine but after upgrade this code seems to be not working.

```
        public async Task AddBulkAsync(List<T> entityList)
        {
            try
            {
                if (entityList.Count > 0)
                {
                    using (var sqlBulkCopy = GetSqlBulkCopy(this._dbContext, this._dbContext.Database.CurrentTransaction))
                    {
                        sqlBulkCopy.BatchSize = 10000;
                        sqlBulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 1800;
                        var dataTable = GetDataTable(entityList, sqlBulkCopy);
                        await sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(dataTable);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        internal DataTable GetDataTable<T>(IList<T> entities, SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy)
        {
            var dataTable = new DataTable();
            var columnsDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            var ownedEntitiesMappedProperties = new HashSet<string>();

            var type = entities[0].GetType();
            var entityType = this._dbContext.Model.FindEntityType(type);
            //var entityPropertiesDict = entityType.GetProperties().Where(a => tableInfo.PropertyColumnNamesDict.ContainsKey(a.Name)).ToDictionary(a => a.Name, a => a);
            var entityPropertiesDict = entityType.GetProperties().ToDictionary(a => a.Name, a => a);
            var entityNavigationOwnedDict = entityType.GetNavigations().Where(a => a.GetTargetType().IsOwned()).ToDictionary(a => a.Name, a => a);
            var properties = type.GetProperties();
            // var discriminatorColumn = tableInfo.ShadowProperties.Count == 0 ? null : tableInfo.ShadowProperties.ElementAt(0);

            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                if (entityPropertiesDict.ContainsKey(property.Name))
                {
                    var propertyEntityType = entityPropertiesDict[property.Name];
                    string columnName = propertyEntityType.GetColumnName();

                    // var isConvertible = tableInfo.ConvertibleProperties.ContainsKey(columnName);
                    var propertyType = property.PropertyType;

                    var underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyType);
                    if (underlyingType != null)
                    {
                        propertyType = underlyingType;
                    }

                    dataTable.Columns.Add(columnName, propertyType);
                    columnsDict.Add(property.Name, null);
                }
            }


            foreach (var entity in entities)
            {
                foreach (var property in properties)
                {
                    if (entityPropertiesDict.ContainsKey(property.Name))
                    {
                        var propertyValue = property.GetValue(entity, null);
                        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(Guid) && (Guid)propertyValue == default(Guid))
                        {
                            propertyValue = Guid.NewGuid();
                        }

                        columnsDict[property.Name] = propertyValue;
                    }
                }
                var record = columnsDict.Values.ToArray();
                dataTable.Rows.Add(record);
            }

            foreach (DataColumn item in dataTable.Columns)  //Add mapping
            {
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(item.ColumnName, item.ColumnName);
            }
            string schema = entityType.GetSchema() != null ? entityType.GetSchema() : "dbo";
            dataTable.TableName = schema + "." + entityType.GetTableName();
            sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = dataTable.TableName;
            return dataTable;
        }

        private SqlBulkCopy GetSqlBulkCopy(DbContext dbContext, IDbContextTransaction transaction)
        {
            var sqlConnection = dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString;
            if (transaction == null)
            {
                //return new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnection, sqlBulkCopyOptions, null);
                return new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints);
            }
            else
            {
                var sqlTransaction = (SqlTransaction)transaction.GetDbTransaction();
                //return new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnection, sqlBulkCopyOptions, sqlTransaction);
                return new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints);
            }
        }
```

This seems not working as expected
`await sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(dataTable);`
I have tried to implement with non-async method
`sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);`
But still, the same issue is occurring
It returns an error

"*One or more errors occurred. (Login failed for user 'Devadmin'.)*"
I have tried Task.Run method It will not return any error but will data will not be inserted into the table.

`Task.Run(async () => await sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(dataTable));`

Please some one help me on this issue.

Comment: `Login failed for user` is nothing to do with what you are claiming, it's simply a SQL Server login failure. if you look at the SQL Server error log https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/view-the-sql-server-error-log-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver16 you will find a log there with error 18456. Please pst the *full* message as it contains extra details to help us diagnose this.

Comment: @Charlieface This was working earlier before the upgrade. I have tried reverting back to the older version to check and it was working fine. All other APIs are working fine. If  SQL Server login fails, all the rest of the API will not work

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, that's the error you're seeing, that's what the issue is. Maybe it's using a different connection string? What does `GetSqlBulkCopy` do?

Comment: @Charlieface I have edited the above code

Comment: This line is the problem `var sqlConnection = dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString;` if the connection is already open then the connection string won't have the password. Either use `persist security info=true` in the connection string, or better just use the actual connection `var sqlConnection = dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection();`. Note that your "transaction" handling is fundamentally broken, as a transaction can only be associated with one connection.

Comment: Instead of retrieving the connection string from the connection, use that connection

Comment: You can simplify this code a *lot* by not trying to bind SqlBulkCopy to DbContext, and using [FastMember's ObjectReader](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member#ever-needed-an-idatareader) to create a DbDataReader wrapper over your objects. You can put all this in a relatively short method. Using a single transaction is *not* a great idea either, especially if you have a lot of data. There's a very good reason SqlBulkCopy uses a transaction per batch. Using a *single* transaction means that everything has to be written to the transaction log and committed before the operation ends

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of adding `persist security info=true`  to the string. we can use following code.

```
public async Task AddBulkAsync(List<T> entityList)
    {
                var sqlConnectionString = SqlConnectionToConnectionString((SqlConnection)this._dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection());
                var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
                var wasOpen = sqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open;
                try
                {
                    using (var sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints))
                    {
                        if (!wasOpen)
                            await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();
                        
                        sqlBulkCopy.BatchSize = 10000;
                        sqlBulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 1800;
                        var dataTable = GetDataTable(entityList, sqlBulkCopy);
                        await sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(dataTable);
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (!wasOpen)
                        sqlConnection.Close();
                }
}
    private static string SqlConnectionToConnectionString(SqlConnection conn)
    {
        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property = conn.GetType().GetProperty("ConnectionOptions", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        object optionsObject = property.GetValue(conn, null);
        System.Reflection.MethodInfo method = optionsObject.GetType().GetMethod("UsersConnectionString");
        string connStr = method.Invoke(optionsObject, new object[] { false }) as string; // argument is "hidePassword" so we set it to false
        return connStr;
    }
```

This has helped me to solve the issue. The connection string was blocking password and cannot able to do the connection string established.

Comment: That code leaks connections. `Persist Security Info =True` is only needed because of the way the question tried to retrieve the connection string.  Had you tried to use the *connection* retrieved by DbContext instead of the connection string, you wouldn't have any problems. Of course, a far better solution would be to just read the same string from wherever DbContext got it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `DbConnection` has already been opened. So when you try retrieve the connection string, the password has been wiped.

You could add `persist security info=true` to the string, but I would advise against it.

Instead, rewrite your `GetSqlBulkCopy` function, which is anyway fundamentally broken in the way it handles transactions, so that it now reuses the connection object it receives, instead of just the connection string.

```cs
private SqlBulkCopy GetSqlBulkCopy(SqlConnection connection, DbContext dbContext)
{
    var sqlTransaction = _dbContext.Database.CurrentTransaction.GetDbTransaction() as SqlTransaction;
    return new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints, sqltransaction);
}
```

And then

```cs
var sqlConnection = (SqlConnection)dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection();
var wasOpen = sqlConnection.ConnectionState == ConnectionState.Open
try
{
    using (var sqlBulkCopy = GetSqlBulkCopy(sqlConnection, this._dbContext))
    {
        //etc
        if (!wasOpen)
            await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();
        // etc
    }
}
finally
{
    if (!wasOpen)
        sqlConnection.Close();
}
```

Comment: I have tried to use persist security info=true in the connection string then it was working fine. But this is not a valid solution. I have tried the above code but still returns error. "WriteToServer requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed." You were right the connection string is not providing the password now.

Comment: Are you adding `if (!wasOpen) await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();`